# ntpd unable to create socket on en1

Tags: network, airport

I see lots of errors in `system.log` from `ntpd` attempts to create ipv6 sockets, running OS X 10.9.1. I have only wireless, so why is the iMac attempting to use `en1`?

E.g.

```
unable to create socket on en1 (1065) for 2602:306:bdcd:efd0:48a5:b2a9:1f08:9add#123
davids-imac:log daviderickson$ grep "unable to create socket on en1" system.log | wc -l
     477

davids-imac:log daviderickson$ cat /etc/ntp.conf
server time.apple.com

davids-imac:log daviderickson$ ps -axww | grep ntp
  115 ??         0:00.02 /usr/sbin/ntpd -c /private/etc/ntp-restrict.conf -n -g -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -f /var/db/ntp.drift

davids-imac:log daviderickson$ sudo lsof -n -i UDP:123
Password:
COMMAND PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
ntpd    115 root   20u  IPv4 0x3447938b9b9ed67f      0t0  UDP *:ntp
ntpd    115 root   21u  IPv6 0x3447938b9b9ed497      0t0  UDP *:ntp
ntpd    115 root   22u  IPv6 0x3447938b9b9ed0c7      0t0  UDP [::1]:ntp
ntpd    115 root   23u  IPv4 0x3447938b9b9ecedf      0t0  UDP 127.0.0.1:ntp
ntpd    115 root   24u  IPv6 0x3447938b9b9eccf7      0t0  UDP [fe80:1::1]:ntp
ntpd    115 root   25u  IPv6 0x3447938b9b9ecb0f      0t0  UDP [fe80:5::8e2d:aaff:fe5e:f9f9]:ntp
ntpd    115 root   26u  IPv4 0x3447938b9b9ec927      0t0  UDP 192.168.1.182:ntp
ntpd    115 root   28u  IPv6 0x3447938b9bba0557      0t0  UDP [2602:306:bdcd:efd0:8e2d:aaff:fe5e:f9f9]:ntp
ntpd    115 root   29u  IPv6 0x3447938b9bba036f      0t0  UDP [2602:306:bdcd:efd0:f51e:bb50:38c4:750c]:ntp
```

Comment: Can you include the output of `ifconfig en1`? If it's an iMac it would have both wired (`en0`) and wireless (`en1`) NICs, whether or not you are using them.

Answer (score 1):

As Tony said, en1 = AirPort on most Macs. To go a bit further NTP(d) is related to your computers time. Have you noticed any issues with time being out of sync or the clock losing track of itself after a restart or start up after being shut down or removed from power?

Have there been any changes to your network recently (a new router or new settings in System Preferences > Network?

There are a few things that could be going on with your system and ntpd is having issues reaching out and might be trying to promote your computer to a layer0 NTP server. Not what it should be doing. Normally the mac in front of our noses is down a few layers so see if you notice any time issues. If the issue remains delete the ntp.conf and reinstall your OS. If issue remains after reinstall then your RTC which is part of the logic board is bad and needs to be replaced.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well your WiFi **is** `en1`.

If you go "ifconfig" at the command line you will see that `en0` will be inactive but `en1` will be up and have an IP address.